# The Newtonian Gravitational field - ode property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $s(t)=s(r(t),\theta(t))$ be a solution curve of $\ddot{x}(t)$=$\frac{1}{m}F(x(t))$, where $F(x)$ is the Newtonian gravitational field on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and h is non-zero along $s(t)$, where $h=mr^2\dot\theta$.

$u(t)=\frac{1}{r(t)}$, i.e. $u(t)=-V(s(t))$. r is a function of $\theta$ along the curve $s(t)$, i.e. $r=r(\theta)$.

I want to prove the following ode but I don't know how to start:
Along $s(t)$ the functions u and $\theta$ satisfy the following ode:
$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta^2}+u=\frac{m}{h^2}$

Comment: This is known as [Binet equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation).